# how to fixTypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn, typeerror, scalar

i'm running below code while i have received an error like only integer scalar values converted to scalar index..

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

      X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
      min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
      X_train = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
      rbm_train=rbm_model_1.fit_transform(X_train )
```

```
X_train=sc.fit_transform(X_train) ----> this line causing error
```

```
X =[[0.00000000e+00 1.76100000e+03 3.02434414e-02 ... 1.00505479e+01
  6.90634415e+00 1.13641060e+01]
 [1.00000000e+00 5.54300000e+03 3.32540176e-01 ... 9.66597699e+01
  7.81453418e+01 2.94180046e+02]
 [2.00000000e+00 3.44800000e+03 1.35616750e-01 ... 2.77757100e+01
  2.95552513e+01 6.49203725e+01]
 ...
 [5.85600000e+03 3.37100000e+03 1.99433359e-01 ... 1.82494245e+01
  2.96294395e+01 4.89311229e+01]
 [5.85700000e+03 4.59700000e+03 3.33133906e-01 ... 4.38591971e+01
  6.63558086e+01 5.51086311e+01]
 [5.85800000e+03 4.82800000e+03 3.91628974e-01 ... 6.50556871e+01
  1.02210562e+02 5.93112050e+01]]

y= [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]

X_train = [[-0.78210062  0.14111439 -0.3656736  ... -0.06997126 
    -0.14909763
  -0.54753418]
 [-0.51177349 -0.77928848 -0.47345634 ... -0.24668018 -0.17406007
  -0.67165109]
 [ 0.07797737 -0.54963283 -0.45941915 ... -0.26573143 -0.21174211
  -0.61647054]
 ...
 [-0.75134129 -1.29734889 -0.59546654 ... -0.328803   -0.25774714
  -0.69402226]
 [-0.18702603 -0.3460879  -0.58283771 ... -0.24237006 -0.26603587
  -0.59759254]
 [-0.11308535 -0.82498224 -0.50012261 ... -0.3001251  -0.22795859
  -0.64925682]]
```

these are the outputs i got previously for X,Y,X_train...  i have  the values but while converting its relecting as only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: You data shape is probably wrong. Can you post a small reproducible example please?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer because it's too long for a comment:

I can't reproduce your problem, please provide a runnable example. Let's tidy up the code you provided and remove anything that's not related to the error:

- remove everything after the line where the error occurs- it's not relevant
- remove the function, don't need one for a quick script
- remove `args`
- you seem to be confusing `X` (uppercase) and `x` (lowercase). You didn't say if the data you posted in the comment was stored in X or x, so in line with sklearn convention I stored it in X.
- The sample data you provided is already the right shape (N rows, M columns), so I put that into the Scaler, and voila:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler



X = [
    [-0.78210062, 0.14111439, -0.3656736, -0.06997126, -0.14909763, -0.54753418],
    [-0.51177349, -0.77928848, -0.47345634, -0.24668018, -0.17406007, -0.67165109],
    [0.07797737, -0.54963283, -0.45941915, -0.26573143, -0.21174211, -0.61647054],
    [-0.75134129, -1.29734889, -0.59546654, -0.328803, -0.25774714, -0.69402226],
    [-0.18702603, -0.3460879, -0.58283771, -0.24237006, -0.26603587, -0.59759254],
    [-0.11308535, -0.82498224, -0.50012261, -0.3001251, -0.22795859, -0.64925682],
]

Y = list(range(len(X)))

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.10, random_state=0)

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
```

which is working fine. Given how much info is missing from the original question I can't be sure what the original problem is. My theory is that the data you pass into the is not of shape `(M, N)` because of this line:

```
n_components_RBM,n_components_nn_=X,Y
```

This makes me thing your original `X` (uppercase) is an integer rather than a matrix and you actually want to use `x` (lowercase). Try to find differences between the data in this example and your real data.

Comment: What's the value of `args` in your edited example? You still have 2 lines above that don't do anything, change them and it runs fine

# x, y, regularization_nn, learning_rate_RBM, learning_rate_nn, n_iter_RBM, batch_size_RBM, batch_size_nn, n_iter_nn = args
# n_components_RBM, n_components_nn_ = X, Y
rbm_model_1 = BernoulliRBM(n_components=2, n_iter=2, learning_rate=0.1, batch_size=1, verbose=0)